# Tensor product of separable k-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I'm reading Lenstra's "Galois Theory of Schemes", available [here](http://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/GSchemes.pdf), and there's an exercise (3.9(a)) I'm struggling with. We define free separable $k$-algebras to be finite direct sums of finite separable field extensions of a field $k$; i.e. $B$ is a free separable $k$-algebra if we can write $B = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n B_i$, where each $B_i$ is a separable extension of $k$.

Question: If $A, B$ and $C$ are free separable $k$-algebras, then given maps $A \to B$ and $A \to C$, how do we show that $B \otimes_A C$ is also a free separable $k$-algebra?

A suggested hint is to use a theorem which says that a $k$-algebra $B$ is free separable if and only if $\bar B \cong \bar k^n$ for some $n$, where $\bar B := B \otimes_k \bar k$. However I'm not sure how to use this, though. Any help would be appreciated!